# How to generate the 1000th prime number in python?

Tags: python-2.7

```
candidate = 1
prime_counter = 1

while prime_counter < 1000:
    test = 2
    candidate = candidate + 2

    while candidate%test > 0:
        test = test + 1

    if candidate == test:
            prime_counter = prime_counter + 1

print "The 1000th prime is: " + str(candidate)
```

I'm trying to generate the 1000th prime number in python for an assignment through MIT OCW. I found this code on the internet and it works but i don't really understand it fully. Can someone explain to me step by step how this code works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
candidate = 1 #this is the number to test for prime-ness
prime_counter = 1 #this is the number of primes we have found

while prime_counter < 1000: #only look for prime numbers until we have found the 1000th one
    test = 2 #this is the number we will divide the candidate by - start with 2 and work our way up
    candidate = candidate + 2 #heurisitic - only test odd numbers for prime-ness

    while candidate%test > 0: #find the lowest number that the candidate is divisible by exactly - % finds the remainder
        test = test + 1 #this did not divide exactly, increment the test value by 1

    if candidate == test: #is the only number that is divisble by candidate the candidate itself (definition of prime)?
            prime_counter = prime_counter + 1 #increment the number of primes we have found

print "The 1000th prime is: " + str(candidate) #print the result
```

In any case, this is **highly inefficient code**. You should try something like the Sieve of Erasthosthenes - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the program gets a bit clearer when you move the `test = 2` line two lines down, directly before the `while` loop.

Then, this block determines whether `candidate` is a prime number by searching the smallest number that divides the `candidate` evenly. For example, when candidate is 25, the `test` will be 5. But when the candidate is 29, the `test` will also be 29, since no smaller number evenly divides it. (Except for 1, and this is the reason that `test` starts at 2.)

After understanding this part, you just need to understand that for every candidate that is found, the counter is incremented. And if that counter is 1000, it means that `candidate` holds the 1000th prime number.

By the way, this program is cheating by treating 1 as a prime, but not 2. But for all numbers larger than 2, it works.